# ruby_on_rails rails 4 parameter is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting the following error message in the log

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: user_evaluation_result:
```

Within the Drills controller under certain conditions I am trying to insert a row in the user_evaluation_results.  The lines of code from the Drills Controller are below.  I have the feeling I am missing something obvious

```
   ....
   user_evaluation_result_req = Rails.cache.read("user_evaluation_result_req")
      if user_evaluation_result_req
        id = Rails.cache.read("evaluation_assumption_id")
        @user_evaluation_results = UserEvaluationResult.get_user_evaluation_results(id)
        @result_list.each do |result|          
          if @user_evaluation_results.present?
            puts "user evaluation result present "
          else
            @user_evaluation_result = UserEvaluationResult.new
            @user_evaluation_result.evaluation_assumption_id = id
            @user_evaluation_result.company_listing_id = 124
            @user_evaluation_result.target_share_price_dollars = 7333
            @user_evaluation_result = userEvaluationResult.new(user_evaluation_result_params)
          end
        end   
   ....
   # further down in Drills Controller
    def user_evaluation_result_params
      params.require(:user_evaluation_result).
        permit(:evaluation_assumption_id,
               :company_listing_id,
               :target_share_price_dollars )
   end
```

The value for user_evaluation_results currently hard coded but that changes when I get it working.

The model for user_evaluation_result

```
class UserEvaluationResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
  before_validation :clean_data

  belongs_to :company_listing
  belongs_to :evaluation_assumption

  validates :evaluation_assumption_id, :company_listing_id, 
      :target_share_price_dollars, presence: true
  validates :target_share_price_dollars, :numericality => { :only_integer => true, 
      :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}
  validates :company_listing_id, uniqueness: {scope: [:evaluation_assumption_id]}

  def self.get_user_evaluation_results(id)
    where("evaluation_assumption_id = ?", id)
  end

  def target_share_price_dollars
    target_share_price.to_d/1000 if target_share_price
  end
  def target_share_price_dollars=(dollars)
    self.target_share_price = dollars.to_d*1000 if dollars.present?
  end

  private

  def clean_data
    # trim whitespace from beginning and end of string attributes
    attribute_names.each do |name|
      if send(name).respond_to?(:strip)
      send("#{name}=", send(name).strip)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

table for user_evaluation_result

```
 create_table "user_evaluation_results", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "company_listing_id"
    t.integer  "target_share_price"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "evaluation_assumption_id"
  end
```

any help welcome and of course can post further details
thanks Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UserEvaluationResult` called here: `@user_evaluation_result = userEvaluationResult.new(user_evaluation_result_params)` is lowercase and must be capital so `Rails` knows you are referring to the `User Evaluation Result class`. You are getting that error because the `params` you defined require a `UserEvaluationResult` to be acting on yet you are not providing one.

Comment: That being said your code doesn't make sense. You create a new instance and then are adding variables individually to it but then on the last line add all those variables again. The point of defining user_evaluation_result_params is so you can add all the params in one go and don't have to define each one individually.You can write the code more efficiently like this: @user_evaluation_result = UserEvaluationResult.new(user_evaluation_result_params)

Comment: Hi kittyminky2 - thanks for the answer.  Could you please clarify how to fix ? What excatly do I capitalise ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1854802 replace your whole `if @user_evaluation_results.present? else` etc... `method` in the `DrillsController` with `if @user_evaluation_results.present?
    puts "user evaluation result present "
  else
    @user_evaluation_result = UserEvaluationResult.new(user_evaluation_result_params)
  end`

Comment: thanks - still one question normally the values going into params.require(:user_evaluation ... would come from the view.  However in this case they are derived values.  How I assign a value company_listing_id for example ?